# Sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int64 found

Tags: python, string, numpy, seaborn

I keep getting this issue when I try and plot p values. I don't understand what is the sequence item 0. I found a couple of similar questions but I still dont understand what is causing this issue in my code below nor how to fix it.

```
from statannotations.Annotator import Annotator

cluster_0_wmd = Hub_all_data.loc[(Hub_all_data.Module_ID == 0), "Within_module_degree"].values
cluster_1_wmd = Hub_all_data.loc[(Hub_all_data.Module_ID == 1), "Within_module_degree"].values
cluster_2_wmd = Hub_all_data.loc[(Hub_all_data.Module_ID == 2), "Within_module_degree"].values


with sns.plotting_context('notebook', font_scale=1.4):
# Plot with seaborn
sns.violinplot(**plotting_parameters)

stat_results = [mannwhitneyu(cluster_0_wmd, cluster_1_wmd, alternative="two-sided"),
            mannwhitneyu(cluster_0_wmd, cluster_2_wmd, alternative="two-sided"),
            mannwhitneyu(cluster_1_wmd, cluster_2_wmd, alternative="two-sided")]

pvalues = [result.pvalue for result in stat_results]

xval = [0,1,2]

plotting_parameters = {
'data':    Hub_all_data,
'x':       'Module_ID',
'y':       'Within_module_degree',
'palette': my_col}

pairs = [('cluster_0_wmd', 'cluster_1_wmd'),
     ('cluster_0_wmd', 'cluster_2_wmd'),
     ('cluster_1_wmd', 'cluster_2_wmd')]

pairs2 = [(0,1), (0,2), (1,2)]


formatted_pvalues = [f"p={p:.2e}" for p in pvalues]

annotator = Annotator(ax, pairs2, **plotting_parameters)
annotator.set_custom_annotations(formatted_pvalues)
annotator.annotate()


plt.show()
```

I get the error on literally the annotator.annotate() line. Here is the error line:

```
runcell(27, '/Users/albitcabanmurillo/N5_nwxwryan.py')
p-value annotation legend:
      ns: p <= 1.00e+00
       *: 1.00e-02 < p <= 5.00e-02
      **: 1.00e-03 < p <= 1.00e-02
     ***: 1.00e-04 < p <= 1.00e-03
    ****: p <= 1.00e-04

    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/albitcabanmurillo/N5_nwxwryan.py", line 421, in <module>
    annotator.annotate()

  File "/Users/albitcabanmurillo/opt/anaconda3/envs/caiman2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statannotations/Annotator.py", line 222, in annotate
    orig_value_lim=orig_value_lim)

  File "/Users/albitcabanmurillo/opt/anaconda3/envs/caiman2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statannotations/Annotator.py", line 506, in _annotate_pair
    annotation.print_labels_and_content()

  File "/Users/albitcabanmurillo/opt/anaconda3/envs/caiman2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statannotations/Annotation.py", line 43, in print_labels_and_content
    for struct in self.structs])

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int64 found
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error in? Could you paste your complete error log in the question?

Comment: Hi @SPSharan, I edited it now it had the error line and all the details. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to try to reproduce your issue using some dummy data.
It seems `statannotations` doesn't like the numeric values in 'Module_ID'. You could try to change them to strings (also using them for `pairs2`). Depending on when you change them, you might also need to change the numeric values to strings in `Hub_all_data.loc[(Hub_all_data.Module_ID == "0"), ...]`.

Note that in your example code, you used `plotting_parameters` before assigning a value (I assume you just want to move the assignment to before the call to `sns.violinplot`).  The code also uses an unknown `ax` as the first parameter to `Annotator(...)`; here I assume `ax` is the return value of `sns.violinplot`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statannotations.Annotator import Annotator

# first create some dummy data for testing
Hub_all_data = pd.DataFrame({'Module_ID': np.repeat(np.arange(3), 100),
                             'Within_module_degree': np.random.randn(300).cumsum()})
# change Module_ID from numeric to string
Hub_all_data['Module_ID'] = Hub_all_data['Module_ID'].astype(str)

plotting_parameters = {'data': Hub_all_data,
                       'x': 'Module_ID',
                       'y': 'Within_module_degree'}
with sns.plotting_context('notebook', font_scale=1.4):
    ax = sns.violinplot(**plotting_parameters)

# also change these values to strings
pairs2 = [("0", "1"), ("0", "2"), ("1", "2")]

# just use some dummy data, as we don't have the original data nor the functions
pvalues = [0.001, 0.002, 0.03]
formatted_pvalues = [f"p={p:.2e}" for p in pvalues]

annotator = Annotator(ax, pairs2, **plotting_parameters)
annotator.set_custom_annotations(formatted_pvalues)
annotator.annotate()

sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout() # make all labels fit nicely
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.violinplot with statannotations]

Answer (score 0):

You could also update statannotations to version 0.5+, where it was fixed.